# Animate multiple transforms in patternTransform in SVG SMIL

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

I have a pattern definition in SVG that has two transform definitions in its `patternTransform` attribute:

```
<pattern id="pa" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" patternTransform="rotate(0) translate(0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" filter="url(#fa)"></rect>
</pattern>
```

Using an `<animateTransform>` element, I'm able to successfully animate a single transform definition.

```
<pattern id="pa" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" patternTransform="rotate(0) translate(0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <animateTransform attributeName="patternTransform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0" to="400" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" filter="url(#fa)"></rect>
</pattern>
```

However I'd like to animate both the `rotate` and `translate` transforms with the `patternTransform` element.

Adding two `<animateTransform>` elements only applies the last animation, since they are both animating the same attribute. (Note, for this reason this question is *not* a duplicate of the question *[Multiple animations on SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028125/multiple-animations-on-svg-element)*).

An article on TutsPlus called *[How to Use “animateTransform” for Inline SVG Animation](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-animatetransform-for-inline-svg-animation--cms-22296#:%7E:text=Animate%20Multiple%20Transformations)* describes an approach to apply multiple `<animateTransform>` elements to a single entity by wrapping the entity in a `<g>` and applying the second animation to the group, but that won't work for pattern definitions since they can't be grouped.

Is there a way to animate multiple transform definitions in a pattern's `patternTransform` attribute using SMIL?

Comment: you want additive="sum" on the second animateTransform

Comment: Ah, that's what that's for. It works!